# Why am i not able to click on open icon in Jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, jvm

Below is the error i get,while clicking on open icon:

```
2021-05-20 12:11:25,651 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge$DetailsTableModel (in unnamed module @0x21507a04) cannot access class sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt.shell to unnamed module @0x21507a04
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge$DetailsTableModel.updateColumnInfo(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:1128) ~[darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge$DetailsTableModel.<init>(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:1115) ~[darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge.getDetailsTableModel(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:576) ~[darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge$SortableListModel.<init>(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:1079) ~[darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePane.createList(DarkFilePane.java:137) ~[darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFileChooserUIBridge.createList(DarkFileChooserUIBridge.java:585) ~[darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFileChooserUIBridge$MetalFileChooserUIAccessor.createList(DarkFileChooserUIBridge.java:750) ~[darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge.setViewType(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:376) ~[darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge.propertyChange(DarkFilePaneUIBridge.java:890) ~[darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:342) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:334) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:267) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8713) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:688) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.updateUI(JFileChooser.java:1838) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setup(JFileChooser.java:395) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:361) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:308) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FileDialoger.<clinit>(FileDialoger.java:42) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:75) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:44) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
```

Comment: Do you use latest JMeter version? what machine are you running it?

Comment: I was using Java 16 and changed it to Java 15 and it worked. Seems to be some kind of bug.

Comment: I got this same error while trying to save in Jmeter https://stackoverflow.com/a/69640910/5506988

Answer (score 62):

Consider changing your JMeter Theme to Windows Classic(Options -> Look and Feel -> Windows classic)

Comment: Installed with Brew on Big Sur and changing the theme has solved several issues, e.g. accessing filesystem. Thanks

Comment: Switching to any other mode apart from darklaf also will fix this issue

Comment: "System" on MacOS Monterey worked for me.

Comment: Like @AwesomeBobX64 said, the 'System' setting on MacOS Monterey. Weird!

Answer (score 32):

The solution was changing the theme!

Try the following:

```
Open JMeter -> Options -> Look and Feel -> Select System theme.
Restart JMeter.
```

Comment: worked on macOS Big sur!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, found this workaround, which is not working for me:

> adding the following to the `JAVA9_OPTS` variable in jmeter.bat: `--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED`

Source: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65300#c3

Instead, using the 5.5 snapshot of JMeter of today is working for me: https://ci-builds.apache.org/job/JMeter/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/src/dist/build/distributions/

Comment: thanks, 5.5 snapshot worked great as a solution

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This might be related to the dark mode of JMeter. Atleast for me this solved the issue by changing it to non-dark theme.
System Info :
OS - macOS Big Sur
Jmeter Version - 5.4.1
Java version - 16
[Reference](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65300#c8)

Comment: Indeed. Its weird bug. There's an interesting article on this issue: https://programmerah.com/jmeter-cant-open-and-save-files-how-to-solve-29451/

Comment: This is so ridiculous I used brew install and install by package and both were fixed with this theme change...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on my Mac and I fix it changing the theme to Nimbus.

I followed the steps that @Дмитрий Попов mentioned before. (Options -> Look and Feel -> Nimbus)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're facing a [JDK bug 482318](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482318), try changing your Java to another version, i.e.

- Upgrade to [Java 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html) (it's LTS release)
- Downgrade to [Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) (it's the minimum version capable of running JMeter 5.4.1)

You can also try switching to cross-platform look and feel by running JMeter as:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.laf=CrossPlatform ....
```

if it helps you can make the change permanent by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.laf=CrossPlatform
```

and last but not the least, you can open a .jmx script in GUI mode by providing it via `-t` argument like:

```
jmeter -t /path/to/your/test.jmx
```

this way JMeter will start and open your test plan (hopefully)

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Unfortunately, setting `jmeter.laf=CrossPlatform` is not working for me. Any other idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to the **JAVA9_OPTS** variable in `jmeter.bat`: `--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED`

Source [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65300#c3).

After doing this step you have to open one existing jmx file from edit tab not from file tab. And after that your `jmeter` will start to work.

NOTE:Be careful! You have to change the `jmeter.bat` file. And also there are three **JAVA9_OPTS** words, you have to change the true one.

Answer (score 0):

Changing theme to Windows Classic works, but it's **impossible to do if the frame is empty.**

Try to launch `\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\jmeter.bat.` This should open jmeter no matter which theme is applied.

And then you could change theme to Windows classic if you prefer launch as `ApacheJMeter.jar`

Comment: This particular problem occurs even when you launch it through \apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\jmeter.bat. And the solution is to change the theme to any non-dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open jmetter on Windows in the following way:

1. Open cmd shell of windows.
2. Go to path where bin directory of jmetter is. Path example:

C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\PROYECTOS\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin

3. Write jmeter word and click Enter.

Note: Jmetter will open automatically.

4. Click on: > Options -> Look and Feel -> Windows Classic (Example)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWqMC.png)

5. Restart jmetter and then repeat 1, 2 and 3 steps.